# How to grant permission to send messages to a SQS queue in a different AWS account?

Tags: python, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am writing a Python application that extracts data from account A and send to a SQS queue in account B. When the lambda function is executed it returns the error below:

"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the SendMessage operation: Access to the resource https://eu-central-1.queue.amazonaws.com/ is denied.",

If I use a SQS queue in the same account it works.

I am using **Serverless framework** and I need to use **ExternalId** in the Cross Account Role.

What I have done:

**In Account A (where Lambda function is executed)**

The function below was deployed using Serverless framework:

```
  TotalCollectorWeekToDate:
    handler: environment.total_wtd_summary_handler
    module: collectors
    memorySize: 128
    role: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_A>:role/FunctionsLambdaRole
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 7 * * ? *)
          enabled: true
    environment:
      COST_DATA_SQS_QUEUE_URL: https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<ACCOUNT_B>/prod-analyser-queue
```

Role

```
Resources:
  FunctionsLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: FunctionsLambdaRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: logs
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                - "logs:PutLogEvents"
              Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        - PolicyName: lambda
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
              Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: VPCAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
                - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
                - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
              Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: CostExplorerAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "ce:*"
              Resource: "*"
        - PolicyName: AssumeCostAnalyserDelegatedAccessRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - "sts:AssumeRole"
              Resource: "arn:aws:iam::<ACCCOUNT-B>:role/DelegatedAccessRole"
```

In Account B (where SQS queue is)

Role

```
Resources:
  DelegatedAccessPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: DelegatedAccessPolicy
      Path: /
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
              - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
              - sqs:GetQueueUrl
              - sqs:ListQueues
            Resource: arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:<ACCCOUNT-B>:prod-analyser-queue
  DelegatedAccessRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      RoleName: DelegatedAccessRole
      Path: "/"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref TrustedEntities
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                sts:ExternalId: !Ref ExternalId
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["DelegatedAccessPolicy", "Arn"]}
```

SQS

```
  DataPushQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: prod-analyser-queue
      DelaySeconds: 5
      MaximumMessageSize: 262144
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 345600
      VisibilityTimeout: 600
  DataPushQueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS: 
              - arn:aws:iam::<ACCCOUNT-B>:role/DelegatedAccessRole
          Action:
          - sqs:SendMessage
          - sqs:DeleteMessage
          - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
          - sqs:GetQueueUrl
          - sqs:ListQueues
          - sqs:ReceiveMessage
          - sqs:SetQueueAttributes
          Resource: { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["DataPushQueue", "Arn"]}
      Queues:
        - !Ref DataPushQueue
```

Comment: You have not shown the code of your Lambda function. Does it attempt to assume the IAM Role in Account B, then use those temporary credentials to `SendMessage` to the SQS queue in Account B?

Answer (score 14):

Rather than creating an IAM Role in Account B, the cleanest method would be:

- The Lambda function in Account-A **sends the message directly to the SQS Queue** in Account-B
- The Lambda function in Account-A will need permission to use `SendMessage` to the SQS Queue in Account-B
- The SQS Queue in Account-B will require an SQS Policy that permits access by the Lambda function in Account-A

From [Basic examples of Amazon SQS policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html):

> The following example policy grants AWS account number `111122223333` the `SendMessage` permission for the queue named `444455556666/queue1` in the US East (Ohio) region:
>
> ```
> {
>    "Version": "2012-10-17",
>    "Id": "Queue1_Policy_UUID",
>    "Statement": [{
>       "Sid":"Queue1_SendMessage",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Principal": {
>          "AWS": [ 
>             "111122223333"
>          ]
>       },
>       "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:444455556666:queue1"
>    }]  
> }
> ```

This is much easier than assuming a role.